# IF Statement with Nested Formula

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested

I am having a devil of a time trying to figure out how to use an IF-statement where I have a nested formula. What I am trying to do is - if a number (B37) is positive extract 2% of its value in the assigned cell and if it's negative I need to assign a value of zero to the cell (B39).

I have included a screengrab of that portion of the spreadsheet. Please let me know what you think - or even if there is a better way that I haven't thought of. I have read other examples, and can't figure this out. I appreciate your insights and time

Thanks.

[image: Screengrab]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
=if(B37>0,B37*0.02,0)
```

Does not need to look for negative as that is <= 0 ...